# DialogFragment - setting initial values and retaining state after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

I have created an *DialogFragment* which is building and returning *AlertDialog* from *onCreateDialog* method. The AlertDialog contains two EditText views.

I'm setting the initial values of these two edit texts in the *onCreateDialog* method which works great until I rotate the phone and all changes get lost/restored to initial values because the *onCreateDialog* is recalled.

So my question is where should I place the initial values so they are only set the very first time you open the dialog and if you have done changes and you rotate your phone, the last state i retained and retached?

Below I have pasted simplified version of my code. One solution could be initializing the class attributes at newInstance() method, but then I need to make them static. Other solution could be passing the values through the Bundle, but no put-methods take Calendar as parameter type.

What is best practice?

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener, OnDateSetListener, OnQuantitySetListener 
{
private EditText editText1, editText2
private MyObject myObject;


public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() 
{
    return new MyDialogFragment ();
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View v = factory.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

    editText1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    editText2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);

    myObject = <get the object from database>;

    editText1.setText(myObject.attribute1);
    editText2.setText(myObject.attribute2);


    bindDataToViews();

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIconAttribute(R.drawable.add)
            .setTitle("Title of the dialog")
            .setView(v)).create();
}

... other methods using getting the values from EditText and putting them back to MyObject
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store your data in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method, and read them again in   onRestoreInstanceState() method. onSaveInstanceState will be called before screen rotation, and onRestoreInstanceState() after change. This is a good place to store data between orientation changes.

Or you can also add in Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Add this value to activitiy, which contains your alertDialog.

Comment: But I guess for setting the initial values I could just use the constructor. It is called only once, when the DialogFragment is created for the first time. Right?

Comment: When you rotate screen, the activity/dialog is destroyed and recreated , so all methods(and constructor) are called again, unless you set e.g anroid:configChange in manifest file.

Comment: Ok, i see. So you suggest that i set initial and last state values from the onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState methods?

Comment: You can set initial value e.g in onCreateDialog() method, then you could save value in onSaveInstanceState and restore them in onRestoreInstancenState() method.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! But would you recommend setting the configChanges to orientation? Whats the pros and cons of doing that, because that would be the easiest solution in my case, right?

Comment: When you set confiChanges to orientations, it's like saying to Android, if user rotate screen please don't destroy activity, I'll take care of this event by my self. The main advantage of saveInstanceState method is, that it works with every event(like phone call). Method always save data, no matter what event occurs.

Comment: My last question, how can i save MyObject to Bundle in the onSaveInstanceState when MyObject is not serializable?

Comment: Ismar you would have to make it serializable or parcelable to store the entire object. Here's a nice tutorial on making in parcelable: http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Comment: @Mike You should be aware that there are other configuration changes besides screen orientation. If you don't handle all of them, the activity might get destroyed and re-created in certain cases.

Answer (score 2):

`Calendar` is `Serializable` so you can put it as that in the `Bundle`.